# unable to get values for react js in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, http

I want to send values from react to node. I am using fetch but I am not getting. Here's the code:
React Code:

```
    const values = {email,pass}
    
    const data = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
    }
    
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/', data)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Node Code:

const express = require("express")

const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

app.use(
cors({
origin: '*'
})
)

app.listen(8000, 'localhost')

app.post('/' , ( req, res ) => {

```
console.log(req.body)
```

} )

When I am visiting to this http://localhost:8000/
i am getting an error
Cannot GET /

Comment: `app.get` handles **GET** requests ... you probably want `app.post` instead to handle your fetch with `method: 'POST'`

Comment: I've tried that too... that also doesn't worked....

Comment: The json property on a fetch response is a function

Comment: you tried it too, didn't show how you tried, you probably didn't try the correct way

Answer (score 0):

You need express to use json body parser:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Additionally you are not sending any response from your Node Server to the client,
try something like this this:

```
app.post('/' , ( req, res ) => { 

  console.log(req.body) 

  const data = JSON.stringify(req.body) 

  console.log(data) 

  res.status(200).json({data: data});

})
```

Comment: that didn't work either.....

Comment: Additionally you need express to use json body parser:

app.use(express.json());

Answer (score 0):

use json body parser:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

You were visitting express' routes not react's routes so of course you got `Cannot GET/` as result.